# Best way to slow down ajax call/xhr requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

Not sure if I'm phrasing my question right, but I have the code below. Basically want to make an ajax request, check the call back, and re-perform the ajax until it gets the desired response (in the example connectedvoter==1).

The problem is it only takes like 80ms and the amount of xhr's gets to huge numbers really fast at that speed. I tried to come up with a way to 'pause' but everything I could think of ate up cpu.

Is there a way to 'slow down' the amount of requests made, to say once a second or two without eating up cpu?

```
var connctedvoter = 0;
var govoters = function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false
        });
        var url = "getconnectedvoter.php";
        var data = {
            userid: userid
        };
        $.getJSON(url, data, callback);
    };
var pausevoters = function () {
        console.log("pausing ajax voters");
    };
var callback = function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            return;
        }
        if (response.connectedvoter == 0) {
            setTimeout(govoters, 150);
            //govoters();
        } else {
            $('#vanid').html(response.vanid);
            $('#name').html(response.name);
            $("#mapurl").attr("src", response.mapurl);
            $('.call').fadeIn();
            return;
        }
    };
//DO THIS TO START
setTimeout(govoters, 150);
pausevoters();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increase the delay of the timeout:

```
if(!response.connectedvoter) {
  setTimeout(govoters, 2000); // instead of 150
}
```

Instead of 10 requests for a second:

```
setTimeout(govoters, 150); // one request every 150 millisecond.
```

---

Note that for start you can change from this:

```
//DO THIS TO START
setTimeout(govoters, 150);
```

To this:

```
//DO THIS TO START
govoters();
```

There isn't really a need for a timeout here.

Comment: Ha, well that was easy... Thanks probably should have realized that!

Answer (score 0):

Just change lines with this code:

```
setTimeout(govoters, 150);
```

with:

```
setTimeout(govoters, 1000); // 1 second
```